# Django user object can not display

Tags: python, django, object

The goal is to show a users images on their profile page. The current error message I am getting is "'Images' object is not iterable".

views.py

```
def view_profile(request, pk=None):
    if pk:
        user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)

    else:
        user = request.user

    args = {'user': user, 'images': Images.objects.get(pk=pk)}

    return render(request, 've/cp/profile.html', args)
```

profile.html

```
    {% if images %}
        {% for img in images %}
        <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" class="float-left" style="max-width: 150px">
        {% endif %}
    {% else %}
```

models.py

```
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', null=True, default='profile_image/none/no-img.png')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  null=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of list of images you pass to context single object, you need to replace `get` with `filter` to return images queryset. Also instead of filtering by `id` you need to use `user_id` to get all user's files:

```
args = {'user': user, 'images': Images.objects.filter(user_id=user.id)}

return render(request, 've/cp/profile.html', args)
```

Comment: Ah thanks so much. I tried filter before as well but the object inside the parentheses must have always been wrong. So was trying other things.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if images %}

        <img src="{{ img.image.url }}" class="float-left" style="max-width: 150px">

    {% else %}
 // other code
 {% endif %}
```

as you are using `get` which doesnt return a `queryset`, thus its not `iterable`

if you had used `filter` then the `for loop` would have taken place